# How to do selective labelling with GGPLOT volcano plot

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, ggplot2, label

I have seen various other threads on this topic, however my issue is slightly different.

I use the following code to:

````
```{r}
res_svsh <- res_svsh %>% 
  mutate(
    customColor = case_when(
      abs(log2FoldChange) > 1 & padj < 5e-2  ~ "high FC",
      abs(log2FoldChange) > 0.5 & padj < 5e-2 ~ "middle FC",
      TRUE                 ~ "low"
    )
  )
res_svsh %>% 
  ggplot(aes(log2FoldChange, -log10(padj),
             color = customColor)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Log 2 Fold Change Groups",
    values = c(
      "high FC" = "red",
      "middle FC" = "orange",
      "low" = "grey"
    )
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1, -1, 0.5, -0.5),
             lty = 2) +
  labs(
    x = expression(Log[2]~fold~change),
    y = expression(-Log[10]~P),
    title = "Volcano Plot of Sham vs High All Samples"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```
````

The data looks like this using the glimpse function :

```
Rows: 1,048,574
Columns: 9
$ gene_id            <chr> "ENSOCUG00000027368", "ENSOCUG000000…
$ baseMean           <dbl> 86.84943, 49.35212, 39.80331, 57.112…
$ log2FoldChange     <dbl> -9.436513, -8.620720, -8.310965, -7.…
$ lfcSE              <dbl> 0.7480739, 0.7504724, 0.7100825, 0.6…
$ stat               <dbl> -12.614413, -11.487058, -11.704226, …
$ pvalue             <dbl> 1.76e-36, 1.53e-30, 1.21e-31, 4.79e-…
$ padj               <dbl> 4.50e-34, 1.89e-28, 1.68e-29, 8.29e-…
$ external_gene_name <chr> NA, "SERPINB2", "SERPINB10", "ARG1",…
$ customColor        <chr> "high FC", "high FC", "high FC", "hi…
```

To plot this graph:

[Volcano Plot of data with colour code of L2FC Red > Orange > Grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlICc.png)

I wish to label just the red points in this figure, with their labels in the table column 'external gene name'. These points could be grouped by the customcolor column under high FC.

Any help how to do this? I think I need to use the geom_text or geom_point command, but when I try to subset the data I cant get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work with subsetting, but because I can't see your attempt, I don't know where it is going wrong. The pattern i'd use is `geom_text(data = ~ subset(.x, customColor == "highFC"), ...)`.

Comment: Hello @teunbrand Thanks for this. I had tried something similar. is .x referring to the data frame - I/e I should replace this with my data frame's or does .x refer to the data frame I am using.

Comment: No `.x` is a symbol in the lambda notation tidyverse sometimes uses. `~ subset(.x, customColor == "highFC")` gets roughly translated as `function(x){subset(x, customColor == "highFC")}`, which is then applied with the data of the main plot call as the `x` argument. See the 'data' argument in `?layer` and `?rlang::as_function`.